# Pyro.Naming.NameServerStarter documentation

Tags: nameservers, pyro

I'd like to use Pyro.Naming.NameServerStarter.start() but I can't find any documentation, and it is better than 'pyro-ns'.
I also don't know why y can't retrieve Pyro4 module since I've just updated Pyro modules. Only Pyro module is reacheable, so I can't even try Pyro4.naming.startNS()

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're stuck with the old, unmaintained, version 3 of Pyro. Upgrade your library to Pyro4 first.

The shell command pyro4-ns is just that; it starts a name server from the shell. Using the API to do it is a different thing because then it is your own code that starts it.
Documentation on how to do that is available here: http://pythonhosted.org/Pyro4/nameserver.html#starting-the-name-server-from-within-your-own-code

Comment: Then you made an error in your installation. If you installed Pyro4 correctly (using pip, is the easiest) you will be able to import Pyro4 without errors.